# what is 'create=true' , connection javadb?

Tags: java, database-connection, derby, javadb

`jdbc:derby:myDatabase;create=true`

what does `create=true` mean? Should all connetionurls hould have this create=true or just user and psw?

Advanced thanks

Comment: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.1/ref/rrefattrib24612.html#rrefattrib24612

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`create=true` in this context means that database will be created if it does not exist. You can avoid using that parameter if you don't need it.

From the [documentation](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.4/ref/rrefattrib26867.html):

> Creates the standard database specified within the database connection
>   URL Derby system and then connects to it. If the database cannot be
>   created, the error appears in the error log and the connection attempt
>   fails with an SQLException indicating that the database cannot be
>   found.
>
> If the database already exists, creates a connection to the existing
>   database and an SQLWarning is issued.

Answer (score 7):

According to http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.4/ref/rrefattrib26867.html it:

> Creates the standard database specified within the database connection
> URL Derby system and then connects to it.

So I'd say that no, you shouldn't have that in all your connection urls; only when you specifically want the db to be created if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4):

this might be helpfull

http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.4/ref/rrefattrib26867.html